# Convert picture coordinates to window coordinates

Tags: python, image, pyqt, coordinates

I am working on Ubuntu,using Python. I have (x,y) which are the image coordinates.I would like to convert them to screen coordinates.The image loads using Qt.Can anyone tell me how this could be done?

Comment: Can you give a code snippet showing the origin or the context of the QImage?

Answer (score 1):

QWidgets have [`mapToGlobal()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) in C++.  I haven't used it in python, but it should work.

So when using it, it will probably look something like this:

```
QWidget imgContainer
QPoint global_pt

# ... After the image is visible and loaded ...    

# Map the top left corner of the image to global screen coordinates
global_pt = imgContainer.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are right in principle, but in your example: `QImage` does not derive from `Qwidget`

Comment: What about the container that the image is in?  It should have some base class that is holding it that is derived from QWidget.